# Twin primes : prove the convergence of $ \lim_{N\sim\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum^{N}_{p\in T} (\log(p)+\frac{1}{p})²$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $T$ be the twin primes set : $p \in T $ if and only if $ p$ and $p+2$ are primes.

Can you help me establish the convergence of:
$$ \lim_{N\sim\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum^{N}_{p\in T} (\log(p)+\frac{1}{p})^2$$

Is it known that ? :

$$ \lim_{N\sim\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum^{N}_{p\in T} (\log(p)+\frac{1}{p})^2=B_2$$

Where $B_2$ is the twin primes constant. Can it be proved or is it linked to the conjecture ? (**The limit being equal to $B_2$ is a guess based on computational data.**)

If you have any other candidate value for the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit should be $B_2$, but we can't prove that.

First of all, the difference between $\sum (\log p+1/p)^2$ and $\sum \log^2p$ (where all sums are over the twin primes up to $N$) is less than $3\sum (\log p)/p$, which is $O(\log N)$. So for the limit in question, one might as well look at $\sum \log^2p$.

That sum is equal, by partial summation, to
$$
\sum\log^2p = \int_2^N (\log^2x) \,dT(x) = T(N) \log^2 N - \int_2^N \frac{2T(x)\log x}x\,dx,
$$
where $T(x)$ is the number of twin primes up to $x$. (The first integral is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, but you can prove that the left-hand sum equals the right-expression directly if you wish.)

If the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture is true, then $T(x) \sim B_2x/\log^2x$, and so
$$
\sum\log^2p \sim B_2N - \int_2^N \frac{2B_2}{\log x}\,dx = B_2N + O\bigg( \frac N{\log N} \bigg),
$$
which indeed implies that your limit equals $B_2$.

But one can also start from your limit equaling $B_2$ and use partial summation in the other direction to deduce the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture for twin primes. So they really are equivalent to each other (and of course, stronger than the qualitative twin primes conjecture itself).

Comment: So we can't prove the convergence without the conjecture ?

Comment: We know that $T(x) < 100x/log(x)$ to have an equivalent to $T(x)$ using the sum on $log(p)²$ ?

Comment: Sieve methods provide an upper bound of the right order of magnitude for $T(x)$. So we do know that the sum is a bounded function of $N$. But a bounded function might still oscillate without converging. Proving that the sum converges to a particular constant $C$ is equivalent (by partial summation arguments) to proving that $T(x) \sim Cx/\log^2x$; so we can't prove the convergence currently, no.